# Adding the items of a list of sets to another set

Tags: python, list, set

Take this example:

```
setA = set("A")
setB = set("B")
list = [setA, setB]

test = set("C")
test.add(list)
```

This gives me the expected `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

How do I get a set `{'C', 'B', 'A'}`?

Comment: Don't name your variables with the same name as a builtin function like `list`.

Comment: @parchment sure, just an example.

Comment: Do you think that you're going to change lists' content?

Comment: @boh I actually use objects and would like to reference those objects in a second set, not change the lists'.

Comment: That's good, so you can use tuples instead of lists =) Tuples are immutable lists, so they're hashable and can be added in sets.

Comment: `test.update(*list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.union`:

```
setA = set("A")
setB = set("B")
setC = set("C")
my_list = [setA, setB, setC]
result = set.union(*my_list)
```

You're now trying to add a list to a set which isn't possible.

If you have `test = set("C")` then you can do:

```
test |= setA | setB
```

This also adds the contents of `setA` and `setB` to `test`.

Comment: I have limited access to both sets (without using a loop) and `test`is already instantiated. `test.union(*list)` gives me only `{'C'}`, `test.update(set.union(*list))` gives me the correct result, but feels wrong.

Comment: `test.union` does not change `test`, so you need to assign the return value: `test = test.union(*list)`. Also, `update` can take multiple lists, so you don't need to union them first: `test.update(*list)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple arguments to test.update

```
test.update(*thelist)
```

> Help on built-in function update:
>
> update(...)
>       Update a set with the union of itself and others.

```
>>> setA = set("A")
>>> setB = set("B")
>>> L = [setA, setB]
>>> test = set("C")
>>> test.update(*L)    # equivalent to calling test.update(setA, setB)
>>> test
set(['A', 'C', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over all the sets:

```
for s in list:
    test |= s
```

Comment: What does `|=` mean? I've never seen it.

Comment: @boh It's an assignment operator (like `+=`, `-=`), but for bitwise or (`|`)